# How can I get the Url of a product from its SKU in Magento

Tags: magento

The question is simple. 
If I know the sku of my product and nothing else, how can I retrieve the url to that item. This is commonly useful for third party integration where the unique id at the remote service wont match a product id. Or maybe you want to make a search box to search by sku only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
$sku = 'ecco'; // SKU you want to load. 'ecco' is a sku in the Magento demo data

$url =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)->getProductUrl();
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 3):

Also.... You could add this to a file named 'geturlbysku.php' in magento root dir.  This code enables a small amount of json representing the product to be pulled easily, enabling small javascript integration.  Product URL is part of the dataset

```
<?php

require_once '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";

$sku = $_GET['sku'];
$product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$fullUrl = "/catalog/product/view/id/" . $product->getId();

header("Content-Type: application/json");

    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($product->getData()).')';
?>
```

Use like this...
www.yoursite.com/geturlbysku.php?sku=theskuoftheproduct

Part of the data returned includes "url_path":"your-product-name.html" which corresponds to the real url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the load method. This is quicker and easier than all other solutions.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('sku', 'sku');
```

For more information on loading products [Click Here](http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/load-a-category-or-product-by-an-attribute.html)

Comment: this code doesn't work on magento 1.7 it says not found, But there is a product with that SKU

Comment: not found, it wouldnt say not found it would just return the model without anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($this->getData('sku'), Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'sku');

$url = Mage::getUrl($product->getUrlPath());
```

You can access the full url of the product based on its sku by adding this to a method and then setting the sku attribute on the class to the sku that you wish to search by.

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /sku.php on line 16 the error is on $product = line... weird.

Comment: If you cant figure out whats wrong there you should look into principles of OOP or replace $this->getData('sku') with a literal value.